# php while loop error

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a `PHP` `MySQL` fetch while loop as shown below in my script:

```
$result2211 = mysql_query("select * from products where is_config = 'yes' ");
while($row2211 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2211))
{
   $sn = $row2211['sn'];
   $allparrentselectq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parrentpro where parrentsn = $sn");
   while($allparrentselect = mysql_fetch_assoc($allparrentselectq))
   {
       $childarr = unserialize($allparrentselect['childsn']);
       $subpro  = '{"catname":"'.$allparrentselect['childname'].'",';
       $i = 0;
       foreach($childarr as $childarr):
           $subpro .= '"Pro'.$i++.'":"'.$childarr.'",';
       endforeach;
       $subpro1[] = substr($subpro, 0, -1)."}";
       $subproa = "[".implode(",",$subpro1)."]";
   }
   $prodObj2 = new ProductDetails();
   $prodObj2->productname = $row2211['productname'];
   $prodObj2->price = $row2211['productprice'];
   $prodObj2->discount = $row2211['discount'];
   $prodObj2->discountprice = $row2211['discountprice'];
   $prodObj2->imageURL = $row2211['productimageurl'];
   $prodObj2->category = $row2211['productcat'];
   $prodObj2->configurablepone = $subproa;
   $prodObj2->configurable = 'yes';
   array_push($totArr, $prodObj2);
}
```

In that I have a problem. I get the result as like below (JSON):

```
[
    {
        "productname":"Veg.Pizaa",
        "price":"350",
        "discount":"",
        "discountprice":"350",
        "imageURL":"http:\/\/farm8.staticflickr.com\/7154\/6694188161_9ee692d854_s.jpg",
        "category":"Pizaa",
        "configurablepone":[{"catname":"Extra","Pro0":"Extra 25g Cheese","Pro1":"Extra 75g Cheese"},"catname":"Nuts","Pro0":"Almonds","Pro1":"Peanuts","Pro2":"Pistachios"}],
        "configurable":"yes"
    },
    {
        "productname":"Core i7 Pc",
        "price":"48000",
        "discount":"2",
        "discountprice":"47040",
        "imageURL":"http:\/\/www.4to40.com\/images\/science\/Basic_Computer_Parts\/Computer.jpg",
        "category":"Pc",
        "configurablepone":[{"catname":"Extra","Pro0":"Extra 25g Cheese","Pro1":"Extra 75g Cheese"},{"catname":"Nuts","Pro0":"Almonds","Pro1":"Peanuts","Pro2":"Pistachios"},{"catname":"Harddisk","Pro0":"Segate 500Gb","Pro1":"Samsung 250Gb"},{"catname":"Ram","Pro0":"8Gb Ram","Pro1":"4Gb Ram","Pro2":"2Gb Ram"}],
        "configurable":"yes"
    }
]
```

But I need the result as like below:

```
[
    {
        "productname":"Veg.Pizaa",
        "price":"350",
        "discount":"",
        "discountprice":"350",
        "imageURL":"http:\/\/farm8.staticflickr.com\/7154\/6694188161_9ee692d854_s.jpg",
        "category":"Pizaa",
        "configurablepone":[{"catname":"Extra","Pro0":"Extra 25g Cheese","Pro1":"Extra 75g Cheese"},"catname":"Nuts","Pro0":"Almonds","Pro1":"Peanuts","Pro2":"Pistachios"}],
        "configurable":"yes"
    },
    {
        "productname":"Core i7 Pc",
        "price":"48000",
        "discount":"2",
        "discountprice":"47040",
        "imageURL":"http:\/\/www.4to40.com\/images\/science\/Basic_Computer_Parts\/Computer.jpg",
        "category":"Pc",
        "configurablepone":[{"catname":"Harddisk","Pro0":"Segate 500Gb","Pro1":"Samsung 250Gb"},{"catname":"Ram","Pro0":"8Gb Ram","Pro1":"4Gb Ram","Pro2":"2Gb Ram"}],
        "configurable":"yes"
    }
]
```

As you can see configurablepone JSON is getting repeated for every loop so I am getting the value of the first product in second product also but I need to seperate like below:

First Product As Like Below

```
"configurablepone":[{"catname":"Extra","Pro0":"Extra 25g Cheese","Pro1":"Extra 75g Cheese"},{"catname":"Nuts","Pro0":"Almonds","Pro1":"Peanuts","Pro2":"Pistachios"}]
```

Second Product As Like Below

```
"configurablepone":[{"catname":"Harddisk","Pro0":"Segate 500Gb","Pro1":"Samsung 250Gb"},{"catname":"Ram","Pro0":"8Gb Ram","Pro1":"4Gb Ram","Pro2":"2Gb Ram"}]
```

I have tried changing the loop but I haven't found any solutions. Kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: foreach($childarr as $childarr): <- wouldn't that cause problems? They seem to have the same name to me.

Comment: @shadow i have tryed changing the name in for each but it causes the same problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Truth What Are You Saying Sir As I Dont Know About Mysqli I Wrote With Mysql...

Comment: @vaahost: Like I said, `mysql` functions in PHP are old, and outdated. Please read the links in my comment.

Comment: @Truth Ok I Will ... But If Possible Can You Solve The Above Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use `unset($subpro1);` after the  `array_push($totArr, $prodObj2);`.
Below Is An example Source
Try This One This May Work

```
$result2211 = mysql_query("select * from products where is_config = 'yes' ");
while($row2211 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2211))
{
   $sn = $row2211['sn'];
   $allparrentselectq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parrentpro where parrentsn = $sn");
   while($allparrentselect = mysql_fetch_assoc($allparrentselectq))
   {
       $childarr = unserialize($allparrentselect['childsn']);
       $subpro  = '{"catname":"'.$allparrentselect['childname'].'",';
       $i = 0;
       foreach($childarr as $childarr):
           $subpro .= '"Pro'.$i++.'":"'.$childarr.'",';
       endforeach;
       $subpro1[] = substr($subpro, 0, -1)."}";
       $subproa = "[".implode(",",$subpro1)."]";
   }
   $prodObj2 = new ProductDetails();
   $prodObj2->productname = $row2211['productname'];
   $prodObj2->price = $row2211['productprice'];
   $prodObj2->discount = $row2211['discount'];
   $prodObj2->discountprice = $row2211['discountprice'];
   $prodObj2->imageURL = $row2211['productimageurl'];
   $prodObj2->category = $row2211['productcat'];
   $prodObj2->configurablepone = $subproa;
   $prodObj2->configurable = 'yes';
   array_push($totArr, $prodObj2);
   unset($subpro1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, your problem in line `$subpro1[] = substr($subpro, 0, -1)."}";`.

So, first call of this line save data from "Veg.Pizaa" into `$subpro1[0]`.
Second call of this line save data from "Core i7 Pc" into `$subpro1[1]`.

Then, line `$subproa = "[".implode(",",$subpro1)."]";` merged all array elements.

Comment: `$subpro` is a list of subproducts for current item. In `while` loop we get subpro's for pizza and save it in first element of array `$subpro1` ( $subpro1[0] contains value: `"Pro0":"Extra 25g Cheese","Pro1":"Extra 75g Cheese"`. After that, we get subproducts for processor and save it in second element of array `$subpro1` ($subpro1[1] contains `"Pro0":"Segate 500Gb","Pro1":"Samsung 250Gb"`. Function `implode` merged both elements to one string for second product. So, array `$subpro1` must be nulled before fill it with new data. By `$subpro1 = array()` or `unset($subpro1)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
while($allparrentselect = mysql_fetch_assoc($allparrentselectq))
{
    $childarr = unserialize($allparrentselect['childsn']);
    $subpro  = '{"catname":"'.$allparrentselect['childname'].'",';
    $i = 0;
    foreach($childarr as $childarr):
       $subpro .= '"Pro'.$i++.'":"'.$childarr.'",';
    endforeach;
    $subpro1[] = substr($subpro, 0, -1)."}";
    $subproa = "[".implode(",",$subpro1)."]";
    $subpro1 = array();
}
```

try this in second while loop